# swift strange copy by value cause different results

Tags: ios, swift

I met a very strange behavior. I have two piece of code. They are suppose to produce the same result **forkey "level"**. However, they are not. I could not see the difference between them.

**The following code produce correct result.**

```
for var i = 0 ; i < ComboAry.count; i++ {
        let dishcount = ComboAry[i]["dish_count"] as! Int

        for var j = 0 ; j < dishcount ; j++ {

            let items = NSMutableDictionary()
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["category_name"] as! String, forKey: "category_name")
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["confirm_status"] as! Bool, forKey: "confirm_status")
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["dish_id"] as! Int, forKey: "dish_id")
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["dish_name"] as! String, forKey: "dish_name")
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["note"] as! String, forKey: "note")
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["packed"] as! Bool, forKey: "packed")
            items.setObject(1, forKey: "dish_count")
            //this level's value is correct
            items.setObject(itemsAry.count, forKey: "level")

            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["extras"] as! NSMutableArray, forKey: "extras")
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["flavors"] as! NSMutableArray, forKey: "flavors")
            items.setObject(ComboAry[i]["specifications"] as! NSMutableArray, forKey: "specifications")


            itemsAry.addObject(items)

        }

        }
```

**The following code produce different result(incorrect) for key "level"**

```
for var i = 0 ; i < ComboAry.count; i++ {
        let dishcount = ComboAry[i]["dish_count"] as! Int

        for var j = 0 ; j < dishcount ; j++ {

            let items = ComboAry[i]
            items.setObject(1, forKey: "dish_count")
            //this key "level" is not correct
            items.setObject(itemsAry.count, forKey: "level")
            itemsAry.addObject(items)
}}
```

The only thing I can guess its something relate to the memory reference. In the first piece of code, I create new object items and construct its keys by extract the same key value from ComboAry. This produce the expect results **forkey"level"**. In the second piece of code, I directly assign ComboAry[i] to newly created items. Then change the value of keys. This caused the **forkey"level"** isn't correct.

**My best guess is that this is probably something deal with object reference. Is there any quick way to solve it?
PS: ComboAry[i] originally does not have key "level"**

Comment: The two pieces of code are not equivalent; The second piece of code doesn't do anything with `j`  - It will only update the existing `comboAry.count` items but it will do this `dishcount` times to each element (once should be enough :) ).  The first piece of code will create `dishcount` items for each item in `comboAry`

Comment: I am kind of getting what you said. What a good way to do it? I don't want to copy key and key values each time. I want to directly add comboAry's item into new itsemsary and give them a new attribute "level"

Comment: How many items do you expect to be in the final array?

Comment: let's save this way. for example the comboAry looks like this a = [{name:dish, discount:2}], I want final itemAry looks like this b = [{name:dish,discount:1,level:0},{name:dish,discount:1,level:1}]

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense.  Is the number of items related to the `discount` value?

Comment: I have typo here. it's "dishcount". So basically I want to break a item with dishcount > 1 into dishcount number of items. Ex. a = [{name:pizza,dishcount:2}]. then final array = [{name:pizza,dishcount:1,level:0},{name:pizza,dishcount:1,level:1}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106687/discussion-between-paulw11-and-user3566769).

Comment: In that case you need to use the first piece of code you have; you can't modify the array 'in-place' since you need more items
You can make it less verbose though, by simply copying the existing dictionary;
let items=ComboAry[i].mutableCopy()
items["dischcount"]=1
items[level]=j